# React - Cannot read property of undefined, although I am binding the function in the constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, electron, react-redux

I have a React Container with the following function:

```
  testy() {
    console.log("HELLO THERE");
  }
```

my constructor looks like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
                    //...
                  };
    this.testy = this.testy.bind(this);
  }
```

and in my `render()` method, I do this:

```
const renderPeople = this.props.people.map(function(person) {

  let myPersonFriends = person.friends.map((friend) =>
    <span key={friend.id} onClick={(evt) => this.testy()}>
    </span>);

  return <div key={person.id}> {myPersonFriends}</div>
});
```

so I have different persons here, I go through each person, then map through all of their friends, and do the same again until I reach the end and have mapped through all persons.
All of this works fine. But `onClick={(evt) => this.testy()}` does not work. It used to work before, when I did not have this dobule-nested structure, but now it doesn't anymore.

I am confused since I am binding the function in the constructor, so what else could it be?

Error Message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'testy' of undefined
>       at onClick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You loose context in `map`. Should be

```
this.props.people.map((person) => {
// use arrow function here ----^
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not `binding` the parent `function`, that's why. Either use `.bind(this)` or use `arrow function`.

By using `arrow function`:

```
const renderPeople = this.props.people.map((person) => {

    let myPersonFriends = person.friends.map((friend) =>
       <span key={friend.id} onClick={(evt) => this.testy()}/>)

    return <div key={person.id}> {myPersonFriends}</div>
});
```

By using `.bind(this)`:

```
const renderPeople = this.props.people.map(function(person) {

    let myPersonFriends = person.friends.map((friend) =>
       <span key={friend.id} onClick={(evt) => this.testy()}/>);

    return <div key={person.id}> {myPersonFriends}</div>
}.bind(this));
```